# How do I choose the implementation of a type been registered with Microsoft Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

Say I have an interface named IPumaServices, and I have two classes that implement it: POSiXmlServices and TaXmlServices.

Now I have another interface called IPumaNotification and the class implementing it is called PumaNotification.  The constructor of PumaNotification receives IPumaServices implementation.

My question:
In Unity, how can I register an implementation of PumaNotification that injects POSiXmlServices in the contructor and another that injects TaXmlServices?

this is what I have so far.

```
using (_unityContainer = new UnityContainer())
            {
              _unityContainer
              .RegisterType<IPumaServices, POSiXmlServices>("POSiXml")
              .RegisterType<IPumaServices, TaXmlServices>("TaXml")
              .RegisterType<IPumaNotification, PumaNotification>();
            }
```

I have not idea how to make it work with the requirements I have above.

I was not able to research online for this issue as I am not sure how describe the issue I am facing.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify resolved parameters into the constructor and thus resolve the instance you want:

```
using (_unityContainer = new UnityContainer())
        {
          _unityContainer
          .RegisterType<IPumaServices, POSiXmlServices>("POSiXml")
          .RegisterType<IPumaServices, TaXmlServices>("TaXml")
          .RegisterType<IPumaNotification, PumaNotification>(
              new InjectionConstructor(                        // Explicitly specify a constructor
                 new ResolvedParameter<IPumaServices>("TaXml") // Resolve parameter of type 
              );
        }
```

If you want to register two `IPumaServices`, you can name each one appropriately and resolve those by name when you use them.